# Creating a mailing list in MS Access where there are multiple records with same surname and address

Tags: ms-access

I need to create a mailing list from an access query where husband and wife are entered separately but need to mail to them with one mailing label

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long windedness of this response. If I understand you correctly, you want to create one mailing label for each unique address in your database where husbands and wives are or can be entered separately.

You didn't provide much detail so I will provide two examples of how to accomplish what you want, one based upon being able to differentiate the husbands and wives with a sex, gender or salutation column (e.g. Mr or Mrs) and the other based on a simple min and max to be able to get each of the elements you need.

Each solution will require the use of SubQueries, which are a set of Select and From statements enclosed in parentheses. Since they return a set of data, they can be treated as a table or query and used in an outer From clause. We will also code defensively to ensure we don't get bit by Null Propogation, which simply means that if any one or more items in an expression evaluate to Null, the entire expression will return Null.

Should you need a little Sql refresher, I would suggest the [W3Schools Sql Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

For purposes of the examples to follow, I used a Family table in MS Access, defined as below:

[image]

Enter some test data, including individuals, married couples and at least one where there are three records with identical addresses.

To get the desired results, we will use a combination of tables and sub queries combined together with Union All. We will start with the best solution first, which is that you can differentiate the men and women records via some column in either your main table or via a foreign key into an associated table. In the example above, we can differentiate the men and women by either the Sex or Salutation column. I will use the Sex column to differentiate them.

In either case, we will use a Group By clause to help us get the results we need. Think of a Group By as an internal sort used by the query to order the data before it is processed. The rules for Group By are pretty simple, you cannot reference any column in your Select statement that is not included in the Group By clause, unless it is used with an Aggregate Function which will return only one value. So in our case, we don't have access to the FirstName or LastName columns directly but can reference them via either the Min or Max functions. It doesn't matter which one we use since by that time we will only have one record with which to deal.

To review, we will need three result sets, one with a single record for a unique address, one with two records for a unique address and one with everything else. The latter case is not expected but ensures they are at least processed should the situation appear.

The first case is the simplest as the code below demonstrates. Technically, we won't really need the aliases on the First and Last name columns, but it doesn't hurt anything and beats Expression1, Expression2, etc when testing.

We are grouping on Address1, Address2, City, State and ZipCode. The Having clause restricts the Group By to single rows or unique addresses with more than 2 rows.

```
Select Max(FirstName) As FirstName2, Max(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
From Family
Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
Having Count(*) = 1 Or Count(*) > 2
```

Next, we need matching husband and wife records. We use two basically identical SubQueries aliased as tMen and tWomen. The use of the Inner Join ensures that we will have a matching man and women row for each and the use of the Having clause ensures we are only dealing with two records.

There are a couple of items of interest in the code below

1. Access requires that column aliases be different from any column names
2. Columns referenced in the Group By can be selected directly in the Select
3. Columns not referenced in the Group By require a function in the Select
4. Use the IIf and IsNull functions together on any columns that may contain Null data to protect us from Null propogation

Within the SubQueries, we alias the functions to FirstName2 and LastName2. Then, in the outer Select, we alias FirstName2 and LastName2 back to FirstName and LastName.

```
Select (tMen.FirstName2 + ' and ' + tWomen.FirstName2) As FirstName, tMen.LastName2 As LastName, tMen.Address1, tMen.Address2, tMen.City, tMen.State, tMen.ZipCode, tMen.GroupCount
From 
      (Select Min(FirstName) As FirstName2, Min(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
       From Family 
       Where Sex ='Male'
       Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
       Having Count(*) = 1) As tMen Inner Join

      (Select Min(FirstName) As FirstName2, Min(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
       From Family
       Where Sex ='Female'
       Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
       Having Count(*) = 1) As tWomen

               On (tWomen.Address1 = tMen.Address1) And 
                  (IIf(IsNull(tWomen.Address2), '', tWomen.Address2) = IIf(IsNull(tMen.Address2), '', tMen.Address2)) And 
                  (tWomen.City = tMen.City) And  
                  (tWomen.State = tMen.State) And 
                  (tWomen.ZipCode = tMen.ZipCode)
```

Finally, we put it all together for Solution 1. The Order By clause is last and pertains to the entire result set, not just to the last Select statement under the Union All. Also, the count and types of the columns in the various Select statements connected by the Union All must match. Column names come from the first outer Select statement.

```
Select (tMen.FirstName2 + ' and ' + tWomen.FirstName2) As FirstName, tMen.LastName2 As LastName, tMen.Address1, tMen.Address2, tMen.City, tMen.State, tMen.ZipCode, tMen.GroupCount
From 
      (Select Min(FirstName) As FirstName2, Min(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
       From Family 
       Where Sex ='Male'
       Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
       Having Count(*) = 1) As tMen Inner Join

      (Select Min(FirstName) As FirstName2, Min(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
       From Family
       Where Sex ='Female'
       Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
       Having Count(*) = 1) As tWomen

               On (tWomen.Address1 = tMen.Address1) And 
                  (IIf(IsNull(tWomen.Address2), '', tWomen.Address2) = IIf(IsNull(tMen.Address2), '', tMen.Address2)) And 
                  (tWomen.City = tMen.City) And  
                  (tWomen.State = tMen.State) And 
                  (tWomen.ZipCode = tMen.ZipCode)

Union All

Select Max(FirstName) As FirstName2, Max(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
From Family
Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
Having Count(*) = 1 Or Count(*) > 2

Order By LastName, FirstName, State, CIty, ZipCode
```

I will post the second solution separately because of the length of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the previous solution, the second solution is more general and would be used if you have no column available to allow you to differentiate men and women in the scenario defined. It uses SubQueries in a similar manner to the original solution posted above, but uses Min and Max to return one or the other of the two unique addresses. This solution is less preferable because it is dependent upon the names of the husbands and wives and so cannot have the husband or wife first or last.

This solution is very similar to the first one posted above. Because we cannot differentiate the men and women, the Where clauses for Sex = 'Male' and Sex = 'Female' are removed. Instead a Having Count(*) = 2 is added below the Group By clause in each of the SubQueries. Then we use the Min and Max functions on FirstName and LastName to get each of the of them. The Distinct statement in the Select statement ensures we only get one result from each SubQuery.

```
Select (tMin.FirstName2 + ' and ' + tMax.FirstName2) As FirstName, tMax.LastName2 As LastName, tMax.Address1, tMax.Address2, tMax.City, tMax.State, tMax.ZipCode, tMax.GroupCount
From 
      (Select Distinct Max(FirstName) As FirstName2, Max(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
       From Family
       Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
       Having Count(*) = 2) As tMax Inner Join

       (Select Distinct Min(FirstName) As FirstName2, Min(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
       From Family
       Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
       Having Count(*) = 2) As tMin

               On (tMax.Address1 = tMin.Address1) And 
                  (IIf(IsNull(tMax.Address2), '', tMax.Address2) = IIf(IsNull(tMin.Address2), '', tMin.Address2)) And 
                  (tMax.City = tMin.City) And  
                  (tMax.State = tMin.State) And 
                  (tMax.ZipCode = tMin.ZipCode)

Union All

Select Max(FirstName) As FirstName2, Max(LastName) As LastName2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) As GroupCount
From Family
Group By Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode
Having Count(*) = 1 Or Count(*) > 2

Order By LastName, FirstName, State, CIty, ZipCode
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your responses, I shall have a go at your solution and if I can't get it I'll post again. Cheers

Comment: Just remember to mark as an answer if it helps to solve your problem.